# How to check if the string being inputted in text field is a higher case

Tags: c#

check the string inputted when the user log in the system.
What happens in my code is that the password save in database base is in lowercase yet when i login using uppercase it can log in the system

```
public void login()
{
    try
    {


        if (USERNAME != "" && PASS != "")
        {
            string login = "SELECT * from rfidprototype.account where username ='" + USERNAME + "' and password = '" + PASS + "';";
            MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(login, SQLconn);
            MySqlDataReader DRead;
            DRead = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
            if (DRead.Read())
            {
                if (USERNAME == "admin")
                {
                    MenuHere menu = new MenuHere();
                    menu.Show();
                    SQLconn.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MenuHere menu1 = new MenuHere();
                    menu1.Show();
                    menu1.ManageTile.Enabled = false;
                    SQLconn.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password", "Laptop Ownership Identifier System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                DiriLogin form = new DiriLogin();
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
            MessageBox.Show("Please input username or password", "Laptop Ownership Identifier System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            DiriLogin form = new DiriLogin();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is the problem? You say you CAN login with either upper- and lowercase, don´t you? However you always should use parameterized ueries as your current statement is open for SQL-injections.

Comment: You need a case-sensitive collation or query. But that hides the actual problem that you're failing to apply any security whatsoever. Passwords must not be stored in plaintext, SQL queries should not be hand-crafted by appending strings. Use an existing authentication and authorization framework if you don't want this to blow up in your face.

Comment: yes but all i want to receive is only lower cases

Comment: Side note: storing passwords as *plain text* is a bad practice; store passwords' *hashes* instead.

Comment: Please! Read up on using parameterized queries before somebody logs in with username `'; DROP TABLE rfidprototype.account; --`

Comment: Because i Have a database consisting of plenty of users. That is why i compared if the username equals to admin the user can access everything in the system. however if it's not then the user has less access of the system.

Comment: Using the username as a means of controlling access to different parts of the site is inflexible. You should look into using role based access. This way you can assign users to a given role to give them the correct access irrespective of their chosen username.

Answer (score 1):

First you have problem with Sql Injection. Read about `MySqlCommand.Parameters` and how to use it. Here is how your query should like:

```
string login = "SELECT * from rfidprototype.account where username =@UserName and password = @Password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS";

MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(login, SQLconn);
cmdDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", USERNAME);
cmdDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PASSWORD);
```

In the Sql Server with `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` you tell the sql server to look into the password with Case sensitive check. For the MYSQL I think it should be `COLLATE latin1_general_cs`

Comment: There is a catch saying that: Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'

Answer (score 0):

So here is a great way to do what you want. Basically convert the characters to **unicode** (I haven't tested the below but it should work, or at least point you in the right direction)

```
public void login() { try {


if (USERNAME != "" && PASS != "")
        {
                    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PASS);
                String unicodePass = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(utf8Bytes);


            string login = "SELECT * from rfidprototype.account where username ='" + USERNAME + "' and UNICODE(password) = '" + unicodePass + "';";
            MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(login, SQLconn);
            MySqlDataReader DRead;
            DRead = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
            if (DRead.Read())
            {
                if (USERNAME == "admin")
                {
                    MenuHere menu = new MenuHere();
                    menu.Show();
                    SQLconn.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MenuHere menu1 = new MenuHere();
                    menu1.Show();
                    menu1.ManageTile.Enabled = false;
                    SQLconn.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password", "Laptop Ownership Identifier System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                DiriLogin form = new DiriLogin();
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
            MessageBox.Show("Please input username or password", "Laptop Ownership Identifier System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            DiriLogin form = new DiriLogin();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```